# Add filters to ffmpeg presets

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I would like to add filter parameters under `ffmpeg` preset (e.g. `-spre` directive).

Suppose a simple `test.ffpreset` under `~/.ffmpeg` like this:

```
vcodec=h264
bitrate=1200
acodec=copy
```

How do we add `hqdn3d=16` to this preset file in order to avoid adding `-vf hqdn3d=16` on `ffmpeg` command line invocation?

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` presets are used to specify codec options only. `-vf hqdn3d=16` specifies filter graph to be used. To read filter graph from a file you should use `-filter_script` option.